# Aggregate sparse vector in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

I have a Hive table that contains text data and some metadata associated to each document. Looks like this.

```py
from pyspark.ml.feature import Tokenizer
from pyspark.ml.feature import CountVectorizer

df = sc.parallelize([
  ("1", "doc_1", "fruit is good for you"),
  ("2", "doc_2", "you should eat fruit and veggies"),
  ("2", "doc_3", "kids eat fruit but not veggies")
]).toDF(["month","doc_id", "text"])
```

```
+-----+------+--------------------+
|month|doc_id|                text|
+-----+------+--------------------+
|    1| doc_1|fruit is good for...|
|    2| doc_2|you should eat fr...|
|    2| doc_3|kids eat fruit bu...|
+-----+------+--------------------+
```

I want to count words by month.
So far I've taken a CountVectorizer approach:

```py
tokenizer = Tokenizer().setInputCol("text").setOutputCol("words")
tokenized = tokenizer.transform(df)

cvModel = CountVectorizer().setInputCol("words").setOutputCol("features").fit(tokenized)
counted = cvModel.transform(tokenized)
```

```
+-----+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|month|doc_id|                text|               words|            features|
+-----+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|    1| doc_1|fruit is good for...|[fruit, is, good,...|(12,[0,3,4,7,8],[...|
|    2| doc_2|you should eat fr...|[you, should, eat...|(12,[0,1,2,3,9,11...|
|    2| doc_3|kids eat fruit bu...|[kids, eat, fruit...|(12,[0,1,2,5,6,10...|
+-----+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Now I want to group by month and return something that looks like:

```
month  word   count
1      fruit  1
1      is     1
...
2      fruit  2
2      kids   1
2      eat    2
...
```

How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in mechanism for `Vector`* aggregation but you don't need one here. Once you have tokenized data you can just `explode` and aggregate:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode

(counted
    .select("month", explode("words").alias("word"))
    .groupBy("month", "word")
    .count())
```

If you prefer to limit the results to the `vocabulary` just add a filter:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

(counted
    .select("month", explode("words").alias("word"))
    .where(col("word").isin(cvModel.vocabulary))
    .groupBy("month", "word")
    .count())
```

---

* Since Spark 2.4 [we have access to `Summarizer`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41731865/6910411) but it won't be useful here.