# Spark Dataset aggregation similar to RDD aggregate(zero)(accum, combiner)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, apache-spark-dataset

`RDD` has a very useful method aggregate that allows to accumulate with some zero value and combine that across partitions. Is there any way to do that with `Dataset[T]`. As far as I see the specification via Scala doc, there is actually nothing capable of doing that. Even the reduce method allows to do things only for binary operations with T as both arguments. Any reason why? And if there is anything capable of doing the same?

Thanks a lot!

VK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two different classes which can be used to achieve `aggregate`-like behavior in `Dataset` API:

- [`UserDefinedAggregateFunction`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedAggregateFunction) which uses `SQL` types and takes `Columns` as an input.

  Initial value is defined using `initialize` method, `seqOp` with `update` method and `combOp` with `merge` method.

  Example implementation: [How to define a custom aggregation function to sum a column of Vectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33899977/6910411)
- [`Aggregator`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator) which uses standard Scala types with `Encoders` and takes records as an input.

  Initial value is defined using `zero` method, `seqOp` with `reduce` method and `combOp` with `merge` method.

  Example implementation: [How to find mean of grouped Vector columns in Spark SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41731865/6910411)

Both provide additional finalization method (`evaluate` and `finish` respectively) which is used to generate final results and can be used for both global and by-key aggregations.